# Adding React Native to an existing iOS app - fails to compile

Tags: react-native

I followed the [official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) on adding React Native to existing iOS apps (Swift).

`pod install` finished successfully and I got to the point when I `import React` in a Swift file and try to compile the app.

The build fails with an error in the `yoga` dependency. Xcode cannot find the C++ standard library:

[image]

However, then I click "Go to definition" on `<algorithm>`, Xcode can find it:

[image]

These are my project settings (I tried a few different combinations):

[image]

I'm fairly new to iOS development, so this might be a simple issue with our existing project, Xcode, Command Line Tools, or my machine. I Googled around a bit, no luck so far.

Any help from someone familiar with iOS development is appreciated! When we find the solution I'd like to update the [official guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) so others don't get stuck adding React Native to their app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is fixed by this PR https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17764, which reduces the number of exported Yoga headers to those that are actually needed to be able to build and as part of that removes headers that require C++ and its stdlib.

Comment: Thank you Eloy! Just curious - any ideas why Xcode can't find the stlib and compile the code even when too many headers are exported?

Comment: I suspect that you are not adding the compiler options to the right target, but that’s hard to say without seeing the full compiler output.